# How can I use a for loop to iterate through numbered variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I've got 20 variables which are named `line1`, `line2`, `line3`, ..., up to `line20`.

Is there a way in Python to use a `for` loop to reference each of these variables in sequence, i.e., iterate through them? Something to this effect:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    print(line + str(i))
```

Although I know that's wrong.

Comment: It's possible, but not the right thing to do. Use a list instead of 20 variables.

Comment: You have twenty separate variables called line1....line20? As @interjay suggested, move those variables in to a list. It will make your life easier.

Comment: They are all lists, each with 20 elements. It's a 20 x 20 grid with a list per row.

Comment: Perhaps a dictionary would me more efficient than a list ?

Comment: Then use a list of lists.

Comment: Related: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use separate variables like that. Use a list. Having a bunch of similarly-named variables is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

```
lines = []

# add 20 strings to the list

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your variables in to a list.

So if line1 = "foo" and line2 = "boo" just do this instead:

```
a = ["foo", "boo"]

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    print("{}: {}".format(i + 1, v))
```

Will give you an output like:

```
1: foo
2: boo
```

Or if you simply want to just iterate over that array then just do:

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Which will simply output:

```
foo
boo
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that it is better to move to a list, but you *could* use `eval`:

```
>>> line1 = "This"
>>> line2 = "isn't"
>>> line3 = "Recommended"
>>> for i in range(1,4):
    print(eval("line" + str(i)))


This
isn't
Recommended
```

In addition to the point that it is more natural to use a list, this also isn't recommended because [eval can be dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). While `eval` does have some uses and can be used safely (though *never* safely on a user-input string), avoiding refactoring your code isn't a valid use case. So -- in addition to making your code easier to read and easier to maintain, using lists or dictionaries can also make your code more secure since then you are less likely to use `eval` in a hackish manner.

Answer (score 0):

lst = ['line0', 'line1', 'line2']

```
for line_num, line_name in enumerate(lst):
    print 'Line str: %s, Line number: %s' % (line_num, line_name)
```

this will print:
Line str: line0, Line number: 0
Line str: line1, Line number: 1
Line str: line02, Line number: 2

Comment: Only because `print` is a function instead of a statement in Python 3; that doesn't detract from the solution being presented.

Comment: But this prints the names of the variables -- not their values