# Python how to loop through multiple variables

Tags: python

I several variables named S1 - S6 and I want to be able to loop through each of them so I can do some string comparisons and manipution on them but I cant work out how to do it

```
  allSeats = "1"

  for x in "S" + allSeats: 
    print(x) 
    allSeats = allSeats + 1
```

So I want that print(x) to do is essectially just print the string stored in the variable S1 for example. Hope that makes sense I dont really know how to explain it

Comment: Your example code doesn't do what you think it does. You are building static strings, not variable names in the for statement.

Comment: Why don't you write your variables as an array? That way you can loop through them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a for loop to iterate through numbered variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153564/how-can-i-use-a-for-loop-to-iterate-through-numbered-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can put S1 - S6 into a list and iterate through that:

```
lst = [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6]
for x in lst:
    print(x)
```

Is this what you want?
I would recommend to learn the python basics first, there are some nice videos on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do what you are trying to do within Python because it is an 'interpreted language,' you can create strings which contain code and then use the `eval` function to run the code.

However, you almost never want to do that.  To do what you are looking for, you want to use a Python dictionary, like this:

```py
all_seats = {
    "S1": 456,
    "S2": 123
    }

for key, value in all_seats.items():
   print(f"Seat number {key} has value {value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with eval keyword.

```
s1 = "seat1"
s2 = "seat2"
for i in range(1,3):
    for x in eval("s"+str(i)):
        print(x)
```